# Store the centroid to a new array or vector

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This is the image

[image: This is the image]
    This is the code below

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    // Read image
    Mat im = imread("beethoven_ode_to_joy.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

    // Change thresholds
    params.minThreshold = 10;
    params.maxThreshold = 200;

    // Filter by Area.
    params.filterByArea = true;
    params.minArea = 15;

    // Filter by Circularity
    params.filterByCircularity = true;
    params.minCircularity = 0.1;

    // Filter by Convexity
    params.filterByConvexity = true;
    params.minConvexity = 0.01;

    // Filter by Inertia
    params.filterByInertia = true;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;


    // Storage for blobs
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;


    // Set up detector with params
    SimpleBlobDetector detector(params);

    // Detect blobs
    detector.detect(im, keypoints);
```

At this portion of the code is printing all the centroid of the blob, but i need to store the centroid of the blob into a new vector

```
    for (vector<KeyPoint>::iterator it = keypoints.begin(); it != keypoints.end(); ++it)
    {
        KeyPoint k = *it;
        cout << k.pt << endl;
    }

    // Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    // DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures
    // the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

    Mat im_with_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    // Show blobs
    imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);
    imwrite("a.jpg", im_with_keypoints);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 for (vector<KeyPoint>::iterator it = keypoints.begin(); it != keypoints.end(); ++it)
    {
        KeyPoint k = *it;
        cout << k.pt << endl;
    }
```

You can do this:

```
 std::vector<decltype(keypoints[0].pt)> vector_of_points;
 keypoints.reserve(keypoints.size());
 for (vector<KeyPoint>::iterator it = keypoints.begin(); it != keypoints.end(); ++it)
 {
     KeyPoint k = *it;
     cout << k.pt << endl;
     vector_of_points.emplace_back(k.pt);
 }
```

**Or even better:**

```
std::vector<decltype(keypoints[0].pt)> vector_of_points(keypoints.size());
std::transform(std::begin(keypoints),std::end(keypoints),std::begin(vector_of_points),[](KeyPoint const& item){std::cout<<item.pt;return item.pt;});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to access the centriod you can do this:

```
for(auto& centr:vector_of_points){
    //centr is the centriod
}
```

If you want a specific centroid. The fourth for example:

```
vector_of_points[4]
```

Comment: what if i want to use the code above and just store it into an vector, so that i can check the vectors

Comment: Then you will achieve what you want and everybody will be happy!

Comment: i tried using what you had given me, there was an error about keypoints.reserv(keypoints,size());

Comment: reserve not reserv.. my mistake

Comment: I did not compile it please try to use the IDE to help you

Comment: how can i access the vector for the centroid?

Comment: or where can i find the centroid?

Comment: I edited my answer, If I may give you an advice, go and read some basic C++ book. You are trying to do a Computer Vision project in C++ with lack of the basics of the programing language.

Comment: im sorry, i cant comprehend what the code really does, cause i'm a student

Comment: Thank you very much, The code you gave me really help out alot! i really wanna thank you from the bottom of my heart, :D

Comment: may i ask, the centroid has a 2 values right (x,y). If i want to check the value of x or y, how should i do that?

Comment: dumb example if(centriod.x  ==5){//do somthing} and same for y

Comment: and please if you have time go to your university library and find a C++ book, you are going to spare a lot of time doing things wrong if you do not had a good start